# Pros and cons of a custom page vs custom post type template file

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, api

Within my current setup, WordPress 4.6.1,  I see the flexibility of creating a custom page and also a custom post type template file.  I do a lot of custom web page development and build pages for a living.  But I want to be efficient with my time and energy when working in WordPress, and would like to know when would it be appropriate to use one over the other?  What are some basic pros and cons?

i.e.

- is one approach more powerful for data handling than the other?
- is one easier to manage with style sheet usage than the
  other?
- is one more flexible for WordPress api coding than the
  other?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is semantical. A page is something that stands by itself, while a post type in a categorization of content. This semantical difference results in different admin flow for both.

The only other difference is that pages can have flexible URLs and you can basically put a page anywhere.

As far as core API goes, you can do everything in any of them.

So to answer your question directly, when to use one over the other depends on how you think the admin will use it. For example for most sites there is only one contact page, using a CPT for that will just clutter the admin UI. OTOH plugins that enable you to create many forms will use a CPT as it is results in a more organized admin for them

Comment: This is extremely rich feedback,  Thank you very much for the details.